# How do i use AviManager?

Tags: c#, winforms

I added as reference avi.file
Then im using the AviManager class:
What im trying to do is to create avi file from some screenshots files on my hard disk.

```
AviManager aviManager = new AviManager(@"..\..\Output\output.avi", false);
VideoStream aviStream = null;
aviStream = aviManager.AddVideoStream(true,4, bi);
aviStream.AddFrame(b);
```

But i don't understand what bi should be and what b should be ?

This is the code of the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using unfreez_wrapper;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using AviFile;

namespace ScreenVideoRecorder
{
    public static class AnimatedGif
    {
        private static UnFreezWrapper unfreez;
        private static FileInfo[] fi;
        private static FileInfo[] fi1;
        private static DirectoryInfo di;
        private static string filename;   

        public static void CreateAnimation()
        {
            unfreez = new UnFreezWrapper();
            List<string> files = new List<string>();
            di = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Testbmp");
            fi = di.GetFiles("*.jpg");
            for (int x = 0; x < fi.Length; x++)
            {
                var jpg = Image.FromFile(fi[x].FullName);
                jpg.Save(@"D:\Testbmp\GifConverted\" + x.ToString("D6")+".Gif", ImageFormat.Gif);
                jpg.Dispose();
            }
            di = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Testbmp\GifConverted");
            fi1 = di.GetFiles("*.Gif");
            for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; i++)
            {
                files.Add(fi1[i].FullName);
            }
            string fname = "D:\\Testbmp\\animatedfile3.gif";
            unfreez.MakeGIF(files, fname, 50, false);
        }

        public static void CreateAvi()
        {
            AviManager aviManager = new AviManager(@"..\..\Output\output.avi", false);
            VideoStream aviStream = null;
            aviStream = aviManager.AddVideoStream(true, 4, bi);
            aviStream.AddFrame(b);
        }
    }
}
```

I added now the method CreateAvi.

Answer (score 0):

Both b and bi are bitmaps.
bi is the initial bitmap and b is the bitmap you are adding next.